# Facebook Graph - Unsupported get request - Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with the Facebook Graph API and some Pages. e.g. `115184661826036, 299277891520`

- In the Graph Explorer it works https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
- Directly from Graph it doesn't work http://graph.facebook.com/115184661826036

Here is the error:

```
"error": {
  "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
  "type": "GraphMethodException",
  "code": 100
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the page is age-restricted (category is "Wine/Spirits"). You need to pass a User Access Token so that Facebook Graph API can determine if you're eligible to view the Page's content.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page#Reading

> A user access token is needed to view fields from restricted pages that this person is able to view (such as those restrict to certain demographics like location or age, or those only viewable by Page admins).