# Error getting facebook page access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi Facebook developers !

I need your advice and/or help about a page access token problem.

With PHP SDK and manage_pages permission I do this:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app->getValue ('facebook_app_id'), $app->getValue ('facebook_secret_key'));
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession(); 
try {
    $r = '/'.$pagefb->getValue ('page_id').'?fields=access_token';
    $pageDatas = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', $r))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage().' // '.$r;
    return; 
} catch (Exception $e)  {
    echo $e->getMessage().' // '.$r;
    return; 
}
```

It works correctly with one of my page, but not with others with error "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api // /205226569539255?fields=access_token".

Of course the request works correctly in facebook graph api explorer.

Don't understand how the same code can work/bug with different pages (I'm admin of all tested pages).

Any ideas ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: Please refer to this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509913/facebook-graph-unsupported-get-request-page?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Make sure you're testing with the Facebook account which has created the app because all other permissions apart from the basic one needs a manual review to let the app work in public mode.

Comment: Thanks for advices. 
I am the creator of the app and admin of pages. 
None of the pages are restricted. But I realized that pages wich bugs are unpublished ! Thanks santosh ;)